# Maintaining variables in function - Global variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im trying to run a script in a function and then calling it

```
filedetails ()
{
   # read TOTAL_DU < "/tmp/sizes.out";
    disksize=`du -s "$1" | awk '{print $1}'`;
    let TOTAL_DU+=$disksize;
    echo "$TOTAL_DU";
   # echo $TOTAL_DU > "/tmp/sizes.out"
}
```

Im using the variable TOTAL_DU as a counter to keep count of the du of all the files

Im running it using parallel or xargs

```
find . -type f | parallel -j 8 filedetails
```

But the variable TOTAL_DU is resetting every time and the count is not maintained which is as expected as a new shell is used each time.
I've also tried using a file to export and then read the counter but because of parallel some complete faster than others so its not sequential (as expected) so this is no good....
Question in is there a way to keep the count whilst using parallel or xargs

Comment: This should output a handful of lines of total counts for the subset that invocation dealt with, no? In which case you just need to collect and sum those output lines, no?

Comment: So it just gives one output for every invocation, I just want to maintain the count.  But want to utilise the multicore feature of xargs/parallel

Comment: How on Earth can `parallel` execute Bash function? Functions are not commands, you cannot just pass them to `xargs` or `parallel`.

Comment: So use the parallelism then combine the output *from* `parallel`/`xargs` again at the end with another step. `while IFS= read -r count; do let sum+=$count; done < <(find | parallel); echo "$sum"` or something roughly like that.

Comment: @firegurafiku: You can't execute bash functions with `xargs`, but you can with `parallel` provided that you `export -f` them. Surprising but true.

Comment: Actually you can do it with xargs as well using bash -c

Comment: @AShah: Yes, of course. The surprising thing about parallel is that you don't need bash -c, making it slightly easier to customize the function call.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from learning purposes, this is not likely to be a good use of `parallel`, because:

1. Calling `du` like that will quite possibly be slower than just invoking du in the normal way. First, the information about files sizes can be extracted from the directory, and so an entire directory can be computed in a single access. Effectively, directories are stored as a special kind of file object, whose data is a vector of directory entities ("dirents"), which contain the name and metadata for each file. What you are doing is using `find` to print these dirents, then getting `du` to parse each one (every file, not every directory); almost all of this second scan is redundant work.
2. Insisting that `du` examine every file prevents it from avoiding double-counting multiple hard-links to the same file. So you can easily end up inflating the disk usage this way. On the other hand, directories also take up diskspace, and normally `du` will include this space in its reports. But you're never calling it on any directory, so you will end up understating the total disk usage.
3. You're invoking a shell and an instance of `du` for *every* file. Normally, you would only create a single process for a single `du`. Process creation is a lot slower than reading a filesize from a directory. At a minimum, you should use `parallel -X` and rewrite your shell function to invoke `du` on all the arguments, rather than just `$1`.
4. There is no way to share environment variables between sibling shells. So you would have to accumulate the results in a persistent store, such as a temporary file or database table. That's also an expensive operation, but if you adopted the above suggestion, you would only need to do it once for each invocation of `du`, rather than for every file.

So, ignoring the first two issues, and just looking at the last two, solely for didactic purposes, you could do something like the following:

```
# Create a temporary file to store results
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
# Function which invokes du and safely appends its summary line
# to the temporary file
collectsizes() {
  # Get the name of the temporary file, and remove it from the args
  tmpfile=$1
  shift
  # Call du on all the parameters, and get the last (grand total) line
  size=$(du -c -s "$@" | tail -n1)
  # lock the temporary file and append the dataline under lock
  flock "$tmpfile" bash -c 'cat "$1" >> "$2"' _ "$size" "$tmpfile"
}
export -f collectsizes

# Find all regular files, and feed them to parallel taking care
# to avoid problems if files have whitespace in their names
find -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -j8 collectsizes "$tmpfile"
# When all that's done, sum up the values in the temporary file
awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' "$tmpfile"
# And delete it.
rm "$tmpfile"
```

Comment: This looks neat I'll see if I can test this tomorrow and make some comments,  but my above example was just a snippet of what I'm trying to achieve the steps involving a du on each file is just one of them ; identifying the sparsity  and and calculating totals is the other.   Performance is key I've got this to work by just using do loop but it takes too long,  I have millions of files to get through ..  I'll give your above suggestion a try...

Comment: @AShah: Honestly, if you can get it to work by just letting `du` run through the directories itself (even if you have to do that twice, once with `--apparent-size`, you'll be better off. You can coordinate the data using an `awk` script, for example. Also, take a good look at `stat` to see if a custom format (maybe including %i, %b and %s) can help.

Comment: I only wanted to pipe my original loop through xargs or parallel just to increase performance (hence the reason for creating the function) ,  but it seems like this is more difficult than I'd thought.... Impression is that xargs, parallel  are only enjoyed for the more basic processing loops....happy to be corrected...

Comment: @AShah: Whenever you are thinking about parallelizing, you have to think about the appropriate unit of execution. If you make it too small, you end up slowing things down because of setup and syncronization overhead. If you make it too big, you might not get as much parallelization as you wanted. `bash` imposes a lot of setup overhead, so you need to make the units bigger. The other side of the equation is collecting and aggregating the results, which parallel does not help you with; that's the second half of the map-reduce paradigm.

Comment: ... in this case, you could improve (and simplify) parallelization by storing the data in an appropriate directory structure. If you have millions of files organized into, for example, a two-level structure with 1000 files in each second level directory (and no files in the first-level directories), then you can parallelize in units of first-level directories instead of file, which will make the `du` calls a lot more effective. Also, the name of the first-level directory gives you a convenient label for the results from that directory, avoiding locking.